# Why the Informix database, change my original SQL code after creating a view?

Tags: database, informix

Hi and thanks in advance.
I would like to know why my code got changed after i create a new view, this happend with two different IDE, Server Studio and RazorSQL, this is an example.

**Original Code:**

```
SELECT T_USER.ID IDUSER, T_DEP.DESCRIPTION DEPARTMENT

FROM TABLE1 T_USER
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T_DEP ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE1.ID
```

**After create a view**

```
DROP
    VIEW orales:vw_test;
CREATE
    view "owner".vw_test (id, description) as
SELECT
        x0.id   
        x1.description ,

FROM
    ("owner".table1 x0 JOIN "owner".table2 x1
        ON
        ((x1.id = x0.id)));
```

I want to know how to prevent the compiler or something overwrite the name of my tables's alias and the clause of my inner join.

Thank you again :)

Comment: Why do you care? The two views are identical.

Comment: As already noted, you can't stop the Informix server doing the rewrite, but there is no reason to be concerned since the rewrite is functionally identical and you can't refer to the aliases used in the view in any query using the view.  (If you were able to do that, then the rewrite would not be functionally identical.)  It's interesting that the owner name is `orales` in the `DROP VIEW` but `"owner"` in the `CREATE VIEW`; is that an artefact of editing the information when creating the question?

Comment: I care because is more easier modify and understand a query when you have the correct alias name in the tables

Comment: By the way "orales" is not the owner name is the data base name

Comment: Oh — yeah (`orales:vw_test` is database:view notation); my bad.  I don't often (ever?) do DDL on a different database from the current database, so I didn't expect to see a database there (especially when it is not repeated in the CREATE VIEW).  Still — my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent this behaviour.

Actually, *all* databases do this. Your raw query is parsed into an [abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) which is stored in the database in a proprietary format.

What you are seeing is the rendering of that AST as a valid SQL statement.

Your original query is long gone.

---

You shouldn't be relying on the database to "manage" the source for your queries. Your original query is "code" and should be managed by a version control system, just like all your other code in your project should be. Doing so means the internal representation of your query in the database is irrelevant, and of course gives you all the other benefits of a VCS.

Comment: All right, well then is nothing i can do but set comments to my query, thanks a lot guys.